# Flutter - Single/Common scaffold between multiple screens with go_router navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router, flutter-scaffold

I want to use common scaffold widget between multiple screens with go_router navigation library.
I don't understand the approach.

I saw some examples for **common scaffold with multiple screens** but they are using some index based scaffold body content widget. **I want some solution where i can use go_router navigation(push/pop/go) instead of any indexed based scaffold body widget replacement**.

**Note: I don't have any tab based or bottom navigation in my design. I want to navigate based on buttons or selection containing in scaffold body widget only.**

Someone can suggest me the approach that can help me.

Also interested in to know which **navigation** lib is **best** like standard and more power full (**go_router vs GetX**).

Thanks and waiting for some response.

Looking for approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ShellRoute. For example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

final _router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/1',
  routes: [
    ShellRoute(
      builder: (
        BuildContext context,
        GoRouterState state,
        Widget child,
      ) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Scaffold Common'),
          ),
          body: child,
        );
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/1',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
            child: PageOne(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/2',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
            child: PageTwo(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/3',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
            child: PageThree(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [
        Text('PageOne'),
        ControlCommonWidget(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageTwo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [
        Text('PageTwo'),
        ControlCommonWidget(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class PageThree extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageThree({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [
        Text('PageThree'),
        ControlCommonWidget(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ControlCommonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ControlCommonWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            context.go('/1');
          },
          child: const Text('Go to Page One'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            context.go('/2');
          },
          child: const Text('Go to Page Two'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            context.go('/3');
          },
          child: const Text('Go to Page Three'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your sample code. It is working as i was expecting.